# tensorflow.js converted 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco' Object Detection Model Produces All Zero Results

Tags: tensorflow.js

I have converted 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17' TF object detection model to tensorflow.js format with tfjs-converter as tf_frozen_model. Regardless of the inputs I provided, the 'model.executeAsync' always produces Array with Zeros for detection_scores output node. I tested other output nodes, they produces the same results, all zeros.

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_frozen_model \
    --output_node_names='detection_scores' \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    /Tensor_Flow_Models/research/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17/frozen_inference_graph.pb \
    /Tensor_Flow_Models/research/object_detection/tfjsmodels


async loadMobilenet() 
{

  this.picture = <HTMLImageElement> document.getElementById("pic");

  const MODEL_URL = '/assets/tensorflowjs_model.pb';
  const WEIGHTS_URL = '/assets/weights_manifest.json';

  tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL).then(async (model) => {
    const image_tensor = tf.expandDims(tf.fromPixels(this.picture),0);

    const result = <tf.Tensor> await model.executeAsync({image_tensor: 
     image_tensor});

    console.log(result.dataSync());
  })
```

The tfjs versions I use in my project:
   "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.13.5",
   "@tensorflow/tfjs-converter": "^0.8.4",

Comment: Could you check if your tensor image_tensor contains the value of your image ? Also can you edit your question providing the command you used to convert the model to js format?

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I checked the image_tensor. It has the value of my image so it should not be the reason.  I also added command I used into the question for tfsj model conversion.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me why you're getting zeros, but in any case if you just want to get predictions it would be much easier for you to use the packaged coco-ssd model: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd.

Comment: Also, your tfjs package is quite old.  Your tfjs-converter is newer and has a peer dependency on a newer tfjs. That could certainly produce unexpected behavior., so you should update both to the latest version.

Comment: I will update the tfjs and see what the latest version gives. Thanks.